# How do I change required/optional for attributes based on the number of sibling elements?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

I have a prototype XML schema - see end of post for an extract. What I'd like to do is to make the "row" and "column" attributes optional if there is only 1 "input" element, but required if there are multiple "input" elements. How do I do this in XSD syntax?

Also, this schema was generated from a tool, and it seems overly complex. Is there any way I can remove the "xs:extension"/"xs:simpleContent"/"xs:complexType" elements?

XML schema extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="foobar"
    xmlns:f="foobar">
    <xs:element name="inspection">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="f:input" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="input">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                    <!--other attributes-->
                    <xs:attribute name="row" use="optional" type="xs:integer" />
                    <xs:attribute name="column" use="optional" type="xs:integer" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The answer to this is going to depend on whether you are using XSD v 1.0 or v 1.1. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML schema 1.0 what you are suggesting *isn't* possible.

Also, with regards to this section:

> Also, this schema was generated from a tool, and it seems overly complex. Is there any way I can remove the "xs:extension"/"xs:simpleContent"/"xs:complexType" elements?

There is no simpler way. Your element *is* complex, as its based on a simple data type, which has been extended. You can make it simpler by giving the element the `xs:integer` type directly, **but** since the `xs:integer` data type doesn't have any attributes, you'd lose the `row` and `column` attributes.